# In R, how to subset data frame in sapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

The goal here is to concatenate the first 6 columns from several files into a data frame in R.
I am puzzled by why method (1) works but method (2) does not work.
To me, both methods should be equivalent.

Answers or hints for debugging are both very welcomed.

Method (1)

```
ret <- sapply(fn, function(x) { (read.table(x, header = FALSE)) })
ret <- lapply(ret, function(x) {x[, 1:6]})
```

Method (1) **correct** outputs:

```
> head(ret)
 $`../pool.11421.poolFile`
    V1    V2     V3    V4  V5              V6
 1   1 M5132 ACAGTG 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 2   2 M6764 ACTGAT 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 3   3 M5597 AGTCAA 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 4   4 M5636 AGTTCC 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 5   5 M2463 ATCACG 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 6   6 M5792 ATGTCA 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 7   7 M6799 ATTCCT 11421 351 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Method (2)

```
ret <- sapply(fn, function(x) { (read.table(x, header = FALSE))[, 1:6]})
```

Method (2) **wrong** outputs:

```
> head(ret)
        ../pool.11421.poolFile ../pool.11422.poolFile ../pool.11423.poolFile
 V1 Integer,23             Integer,48             Integer,48
 V2 Character,23           Character,48           Character,48
 V3 Character,23           Character,48           Character,48
 V4 Integer,23             Integer,48             Integer,48
 V5 Integer,23             Integer,48             Integer,48
 V6 Character,23           Character,48           Character,48
```

Comment: What happens when you add simplify=FALSE to the sapply in (2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second method returns an array. `sapply` has the `simplify` argument. If `TRUE` `simplify2array` is called and R tries to convert your data to a vector or an array. See `?sapply` for details.

Try instead:

```
ret <- sapply(fn, function(x) { (read.table(x, header = FALSE))[, 1:6]}, simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: A corollary is probably that `sapply` is almost certainly the wrong tool here. I was going to also point out that in method 1, each data frame read in may have different numbers of columns, and hence have different lengths, so `sapply` isn't even attempting to simplify them, which allows the second `lapply` call to work as intended. In the second method, forcing the same number of columns each time forces the simplification attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the answers from both of you. I learned simplify option in `sapply` and when it will work. @joran, you have mentioned here I should not use `sapply`. What tool do you suggest?

Comment: @zhanxw I meant only that `sapply` is simply a wrapper for `lapply` that does some convenient simplifications. If you don't want/need those simplifications, it probably makes more sense to just use `lapply`, and stitch them all together via something like `do.call(rbind,...)`.

Comment: @Joran, the same question but in many multivariate time series data, how can I select the rows backwards starting from the end of each time series?